# Having problem when trying to use decoded base64 string on curl request in github actions

Tags: github, curl, yaml, action

I am having a problem where I want to use the encoded base64 for a markdown string to be used as a payload for curl request

below is the example

```yaml
      - name: Create Release
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          BODY: $(echo ${{ github.event.client_payload.body }} | base64 -di)
        run: |
          echo ${{ env.BODY }}

          RESPONSE=$(curl -L \
          -X POST \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
          -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
          -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
          https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/releases \
          -d '{
            "tag_name":"${{ github.event.client_payload.tag_name }}",
            "name":"${{ env.RELEASE_NAME }}",
            "body":"${{ env.BODY }}",
            "draft":true,
            "prerelease":false,
            "generate_release_notes":false
          }')

          RELEASE_ID=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | jq -r '.id')

          echo "Created release with ID: $RELEASE_ID"
          echo "$RESPONSE"
```

When I echo the value, the decoded string comes out fine as expected,
However when I add the value to the `"body"` inside the payload, and request, the body value
stays like `"$(echo {base64 string} | base64 -di)"`

I want to be able to have full markdown format string to be used on the `"body"` value